# bluetooth refusing to restart

Tags: bluetooth, services

i have been trying to use some development blue low energy library that require some pyhton modules and experimental ble mode

library requirements: https://github.com/NordicPlayground/fw-nrfconnect-nrf/tree/master/scripts/shell/ble_console

after installing those libraries,

i got the following response for: $ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth

> Failed to restart bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
> See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.

and after checking the status of the bluetooth service using: systemctl status bluetooth.service

i got:

> bluetooth.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
> bluetooth.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Invalid argument

[screenshot shows the error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJjJ8.png)

Comment: So remove that "libraries" and all should work. The question why they break BT is off-topic.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did so, but nothing changed
even the bluetooth settings gui refuses to change the on/off switch
I think it counters the same error in the pictures